# Google Sheets: How can I query all names and display it in another sheet according to it's category?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

So I have an employee list and a checkbox according to their skills.

[image]

How can I get the employee list and display them to another sheet?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a table of employees and skills. The skills are represented by checkboxes, and a "checked" box indicates that the employee has the relevant skill for that column.

You want to create a dropdown list of skills that will display the names of the relevant employees

Enter this formula in Cell B6 of the sheet containing the dropdown.

`=query(data!A1:D5,"select A where "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B3,data!B1:D1,0)+1,4), "1", "")&" = true",0)`

**Assumptions:**

- employee/skills data is on sheet="data".
- the headers are in row 1.
- dropdown is on a separate sheet; the name of the sheet is unimportant.
- dropdown is in cell B3

**Comments:**

The `select` statement is completely predictable:

- dropdown = WordPress: "select A where B=true"
- dropdown = HTML; "select A where C=true"
- dropdown = Bootstrap; "select A where D=true"

In each case, the variable is the column letter for the dropdown choice. This value is supplied by the following formula.

`SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B3,data!B1:D1,0)+1,4), "1", "")`

This can be broken down as follows:

`match(B3,data!B1:D1,0)+1`

- gets the index number of the dropdown string (from B3) in the data headers.
- the purpose of `+1` is to adjust for Column A.
- the result is an integer that equals the column number of the dropdown string in Cell B3.

`ADDRESS(1,match(B3,data!B1:D1,0)+1,4)`

- returns the cell address of the dropdown string (assuming row#1 - the header row).

`SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B3,data!B1:D1,0)+1,4), "1", "")`

- takes the cell address returned by "ADDRESS()". The address will refer to a cell in row 1, and the "SUBSTITUTE" function will remove the row number (1).
- result is the column letter of the dropdown string which is inserted into the `where` clause of the query.